# Streaming API statuses/filter.json?track not delivering JSON Python

Tags: python, json, twitter, stream, instance

I am outputing a Twitter stream ("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=term") to a file using Python. However, the file is outputting an "instance" instead of a "json" (see relevant part in bold):

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib2 as urllib
import json

# Filled correctly, no authentication problem
api_key = "XXX"
api_secret = "XXX"
access_token_key = "XXX"
access_token_secret = "XXX"


_debug = 0

oauth_token    = oauth.Token(key=access_token_key, secret=access_token_secret)
oauth_consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=api_key, secret=api_secret)

signature_method_hmac_sha1 = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()

http_method = "GET"


http_handler  = urllib.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=_debug)
https_handler = urllib.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=_debug)

'''
Construct, sign, and open a twitter request
using the hard-coded credentials above.
'''
def twitterreq(url, method, parameters):
  req = oauth.Request.from_consumer_and_token(oauth_consumer,
                                             token=oauth_token,
                                             http_method=http_method,
                                             http_url=url, 
                                             parameters=parameters)

  req.sign_request(signature_method_hmac_sha1, oauth_consumer, oauth_token)

  headers = req.to_header()

  if http_method == "POST":
    encoded_post_data = req.to_postdata()
  else:
    encoded_post_data = None
    url = req.to_url()

  opener = urllib.OpenerDirector()
  opener.add_handler(http_handler)
  opener.add_handler(https_handler)

  response = opener.open(url, encoded_post_data)

  return response


**def fetchcontinuousstream():
  # For streaming of tweets use
  url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=term"
  parameters = []
  response = twitterreq(url, "GET", parameters)
  print "Type of the response"
  print type(response)
  for line in response:
    print type(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  fetchcontinuousstream()**
```

The result is this:

```
Type of the response
<type 'instance'>
<type 'str'>
```

So basically the response is an instance, not a json/dict, each line is just a string...

How can I obtain a JSON instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the response with `json.loads`

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib2 as urllib
from json import loads

# Filled correctly, no authentication problem
api_key = "xxxx"
api_secret = "xxxx"
access_token_key = "xxxx"
access_token_secret = "xxxx"


_debug = 0

oauth_token = oauth.Token(key=access_token_key, secret=access_token_secret)
oauth_consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=api_key, secret=api_secret)

signature_method_hmac_sha1 = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()

http_method = "GET"


http_handler = urllib.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=_debug)
https_handler = urllib.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=_debug)


def twitterreq(url, method, parameters):
    '''Construct, sign, and open a twitter request
    using the hard-coded credentials above.
    '''
    req = oauth.Request.from_consumer_and_token(oauth_consumer,
                                                token=oauth_token,
                                                http_method=http_method,
                                                http_url=url,
                                                parameters=parameters)

    req.sign_request(signature_method_hmac_sha1, oauth_consumer, oauth_token)

    if http_method == "POST":
        encoded_post_data = req.to_postdata()
    else:
        encoded_post_data = None

    url = req.to_url()

    opener = urllib.OpenerDirector()
    opener.add_handler(http_handler)
    opener.add_handler(https_handler)

    response = opener.open(url, encoded_post_data)

    return response

def fetchcontinuousstream():
    # For streaming of tweets use
    url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=term"
    parameters = []
    response = twitterreq(url, "GET", parameters)
    for line in response:
        print loads(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fetchcontinuousstream()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, if I try with this code:

`response = json.loads(twitterreq(url, "GET", parameters))`

it doesn't work:

`File "print.py", line 64, in fetchcontinuousstream
    response = json.loads(twitterreq(url, "GET", parameters))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: If I add loads() on the line instead:

`for line in response:
    tweet = json.loads(line)`

It doesn't work either:

`File "print.py", line 67, in fetchcontinuousstream
    tweet = json.loads(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Answer (score 0):

The json loader was reading an empty line and failing to decode, this code will work

```
def fetchcontinuousstream():
  # For streaming of tweets use
  url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=term"
  parameters = []
  response = twitterreq(url, "GET", parameters)
  for line in response:
    if line != "":
      tweet = json.loads(line)
      print tweet["text"]
```